# Using the word "sich nähern" ("approach") metaphorically

Tags: translation, english-to-german

The verb *approach* has a very large usage in English, a ship approaches to the harbour, a man approaches to a kind etc. It also refers to mental operations, e.g. "Learners approach the learning situations in different ways.".
My question is, does the German equivalent of *approach*, *sich nähern*, has the same usage? Which of my following translation attempts is better?

> Lernende gehen an Lernsituationen auf unterschiedliche Weise heran.
>
> Die Lernenden nähern sich Lernsituationen auf unterschiedliche Weise.

Comment: Your example sentences had a few minor issues unrelated to your question. As the oldest answer below already fixed those sentences without explicitly mentioning your errors, I could edit your question to fix those issues.

Answer (score 3):

> Lernende gehen an Lernsituationen auf unterschiedliche Weise heran.
>
> Die Lernenden nähern sich Lernsituationen auf unterschiedliche Weise.

I like the second one better. But a "Lernsituation" sounds to me much more like something you're **in** and not something you could approach - it would be more a question of how to deal with it:

> Lernende gehen auf unterschiedliche Weise mit den Lernsituationen um.